# mod_rewrite between domains but keep links

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was asked to figure out a way to make a dynamic redirect, so here i am ,asking for help :)

I would like to accomplish the following.

If someone visits

URL 1: http://www.example1.com/somefolder/**12324567**

REDIRECT TO

URL 2:: http://app.example2.com/ecosuite/applic/shoplink/shoplink.php?msdsCid=1004730&viewForm=pdf&msdsLang=2&msdsEr=**1234567**

Everything in URL 2 , is static besides the LAST entry, which is a partnumber, and is the ONLY value that will change.

Is this at all possible with url_rewrite, in my mind it should be :)

Comment: Redirect or pass-through rewrite? The former changes the URL in the browser, while the latter re-processes the request server side.

Comment: @Pietu1998 It's not the same domain in the URL 2 link...

Comment: @Pietu1998 Redirect would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can put in `.htaccess` file in the `/somefolder` directory:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule (\d+) http://app.example2.com/ecosuite/applic/shoplink/shoplink.php?msdsCid=1004730&viewForm=pdf&msdsLang=2&msdsEr=$1 [L]
```

If your id is not only numbers, you can change RewriteRule `(\d+)` in `(.+)`

If you prefer to use root `.htaccess` with more than one domain, you can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example1\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^somefolder/(\d+) http://app.example2.com/ecosuite/applic/shoplink/shoplink.php?msdsCid=1004730&viewForm=pdf&msdsLang=2&msdsEr=$1 [L]
```

Comment: hi @Croises
Thanks for taking time to help me. The ReWriteRule is to be put in the .htaccess / httpd.conf that is alread on the webserver. This server takes care of more then one domain, so i think i need something more ?

Comment: It's easier to make a new `.htaccess` file in the `/somefolder` directory. But I will add that to my answer now.

Comment: that never crossed my mind of course it is, well i'll just go sit in a corner for a while..

Comment: i did as you suggested. Created the .htaccess in the "somefolder" directory didn't work tho.

www.example1.com/sbd/1234567 doesn't redirect. i only get a 403 back at me :(

Comment: In this case, you put it in the `sbd` directory, right ?

Comment: yes sir/madame i did. Just to make sure here is the "full" .htaccess with the "right" domain-names in :)

RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?dahl\.se$
 
RewriteRule ^sdb/(\d+)http://app.ecoonline.com/ecosuite/applic/shoplink/shoplink.php?msdsCid=1004730&viewForm=pdf&msdsLang=2&msdsEr=$1 [L]

Comment: NO!!! In the directory, you don't have to change my first code ! You can test the domain with RewriteCond (I don't think you need...), but all the links are relatives to the folder... `RewriteRule (\d+) http:...`

Comment: Sorry @Croises i was to tired. I understand what you mean now.
If using the .htaccess in the ../htdocs/sbd directory ill use your first code , and if in httpd.conf the second one. 

However none of them works out for me :(

Thanks so much for taking the time anyway